# SHMultiFileProperties with c++

Tags: c++

Seen an example of using SHMultiFileProperties on the site with c# but I'm really having trouble using it with unmanaged c++. I am a beginner so i would appreciate any help or maybe a small example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is commented out, you might take a look at [shareaza/CtrlLibraryFileView.cpp](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#X_1VXq0XKpU/trunk/shareaza/CtrlLibraryFileView.cpp&q=SHMultiFileProperties&sa=N&cd=4&ct=rc).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out later that day when i post so i decided to put my code up here maybe someone has the difficulty using the function.
The parameter for the functions are nrFiles and a string with all the files delimited by a '|' . Example ShowPropertiesByPath("C:\Windows|C:\Program Files",2) //if i remember correctly

```
    void ShowPropertiesByPath(CString csFilePath,int nrFiles)
    {
    LPITEMIDLIST *pidlDrives = (LPITEMIDLIST *)malloc(sizeof(LPITEMIDLIST)*nrFiles);
    IShellFolder* psfDesktop;
    IDataObject* pdata;
    HRESULT hr;
    ULONG chEaten=0, dwAttributes=0;
    int i=0;
    hr = SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(NULL, CSIDL_DRIVES, pidlDrives);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = SHGetDesktopFolder(&psfDesktop);


        do{
        CString currentFilePath;
        int delimitatorPosition;
        delimitatorPosition = csFilePath.Find(L'|');
        currentFilePath = csFilePath.Left(delimitatorPosition);
        csFilePath.Delete(0,delimitatorPosition+1);
        psfDesktop->ParseDisplayName(NULL,
                                    NULL,
                                    currentFilePath.GetBuffer(),
                                    &chEaten,
                                    (LPITEMIDLIST*)&pidlDrives[i],
                                    &dwAttributes);
        i++;
        }while(!csFilePath.IsEmpty() && i<nrFiles);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
        hr = psfDesktop->GetUIObjectOf(NULL, 
                                        nrFiles, 
                                        (LPCITEMIDLIST*)pidlDrives,
                                        IID_IDataObject, 
                                        NULL, 
                                        (void**)&pdata);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
            CoInitialize(NULL);
            hr=SHMultiFileProperties(pdata,0);

            //hr = psfDesktop->CreateViewObject(NULL, IID_IShellFolder, (void**)&psfDesktop);

            pdata->Release();
            CoUninitialize();
            }
        psfDesktop->Release();
        } 
    for(i=0;i<nrFiles;i++)
        ILFree(pidlDrives[i]);}
    }
```